# What is an Equals Operator and how does it work?

Tags: c++, constructor, linked-list

New to C++ and I need help understanding what a piece of code does. I was given a header file with a bunch of functions I need to define but I'm a little lost on what one means or how I would even begin to define it.

HERE IT IS:`List& operator = (const List& source);`

Also if you could show me how I would begin to define it that would really help. Because so far this is how I learned to define functions:

```
ClassName::FunctionName {
//Code goes here
}
```

So is this how I would do it?

```
List::List& {
//Code goes here
}
```

Comment: That's an [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). Basically, adding (overloading) the `=` behavior for the class.

Comment: You should spend some time studying C++. Here's [a list of books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Operator overloading is a cool thing you will find in a lot of languages. The nice thing is that it add functions to enable conventional notation to something you create (class, struct). For example, if you created a new class and want to sort it, you can overload the `<` operator and use [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Answer (score -1):

```
ClassName::FunctionName {
    //Code goes here
}
```

is not right. It should be

```
ReturnType ClassName::FunctionName(Parameters) {
    //Code goes here
}
```

Now in your example the class name is `List`, the return type is `List&`, the function name is `operator=` and the parameters are `const List& source`. So

```
List& List::operator=(const List& source) {
    //Code goes here
}
```